# How to initialise private member variable

Tags: objective-c

In the below code I want to declare a private instance variable and initialise it to zero
But when I try to initialise it to zero I receive irrelevant error “; comma expected at the end of the statement”

As an attempt to solve the issue, I tried to find out to which value this variable is initialised:

```
-(void) startRecursion: (UIView *) uiviews {
    if (!uiviews) {
    return;
    }
    NSLog(@"numOfMethodCalls: %d", ++self->numOfMethodCalls);
    NSUInteger *countOfSubViews = [uiviews.subviews count];
}
```

However, the log printed :

```
2019-11-10 14:08:25.711847+0100 UIEnhancement_00[10065:383388] numOfMethodCalls: 8
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue

**code**:

```
@interface UIEnhancements : NSObject {
 NSUInteger *numOfMethodCalls;
}

+(id) initSelf;
```

Comment: 1. Which line is causing the error? 2. Get rid of the asterisks on any line declaring an `NSUInteger` variable. `NSUInteger` is a primitive type, not a class. 3. Do not put declare private ivars in the public `@interface` declaration.

Comment: would you please provide an example!!

Answer (score 1):

*Instance* variables are automatically initialised to zero in Objective-C.

Your code is printing `8` as you declared your variable as `NSUInteger *` – a pointer (`*`) to an `NSUInteger`. Now on a 64-bit platform an `NSUInteger` is 8 bytes long.

(Objective-)C defines the operator `++` on a *pointer* to increment it by the size of whatever type it points at. So `numOfMethodCalls` was initialised to `0` automatically and then the `++` added `8` to it.

Instance variables are best private, as you state you intended, but you have declared it publicly in the `@interface`. The best way is to declare it in the implementation:

```
@implementation UIEnhancements
{
   NSUInteger numOfMethodCalls;
}

...

@end
```

Lastly though you don't show an implementation you declare:

```
+(id) initSelf;
```

in your interface. Only methods which are initialisation methods should start with `init`, they are *instance* methods, and in modern Objective-C are normally declared to return `instancetype` (rather than `id`) which improves compile-time type checks. In summary:

```
- (instancetype) initSelf;
```

though if it is your only initialisation method you should call it simply `init`.

HTH